# How to check ng-model variable value undefined using ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if value is not selected for ng-model `selectedFileSize` its throwing error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined` when i click on button `startRecording`. How can i resolve this problem ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFileSize" ng-options="item as item.value for item in FileSizeOptions" ng-change="onSizeChange()"><option value="">Select</option></select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
 if (($scope.selectedFileSize.size !== "") || ($scope.selectedFileSize !== undefined)) {
    //logic  here 

}
```

Comment: Can you show us more of how you instantiated the `selectedFileSize` object?  It sounds like the selectedFileSize is still undefined at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that `selectedFileSize` is populated before checking `selectedFileSize.size`:

```
if ($scope.selectedFileSize && $scope.selectedFileSize.size) {
    //logic  here 
}
```

Comment: perfect it worked that's what i was looking for, Thank you boss!